# Merging shapefiles with DBF file, error with duplicate values

Tags: merge, geoda

When I try to merge my household data file in a .dbf format with my shapefile by using key variable, I get the following error message:

> Chosen table merge key field IL contains undefined or duplicate values. Key fields must contain valid unique values.

[image]

Because, in my dbf file, provinces have several observations. However, my shapefile has just name of the provinces. So how can I merge these two files in GeoDa?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Please be sure to always include the complete error in the question *as text* -- this allows others with the same problem to search for your answer **and** it avoids legibility issues on a diverse array of platforms.

Answer (score 2):

*I think the error message tells you pretty clear what the problem is!*

**Just make sure that both files have an attribute column with unique values.**

Edit at least on of your files and change keys in column `IL` for example by adding the number 1000.

```
IL (old)    IL (new)
1           1001
10          1010
11          1011
12          1012
13          1013
...         ...
```

When your are sure that both files have unique keys you can merge them again.

Hope that helps!

---

*If you have in both files the same key you might not looking for a **merge** but a **join** of your data!*